# Meteor application - object appears in the terminal, but DATA appears undefined on the client side

Tags: meteor

```js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.methods({
  'harmonized'(text){
    HTTP.call( 'GET', 'https://hts.usitc.gov/api/search', { params: {
      "query": text
    }}, function( error, response ) {
      if ( error ) {
        console.log( error );
      } else {
        return response.data.results;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The above code gives me the array of objects in my terminal

```js
import './shipping_steps.html';
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http'

Template.shipping_steps.events({
  // data: [],
  'submit .hs': function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    //get Input value
    const target = event.target;
    const text = target.search.value;

    //clear the form
    target.search.value = "";

    const data = Meteor.call('harmonized', text);
    console.log(data);

    return false;
   }
})
```

When I try to store the array of objects on the client, I am not 
able to do so and client logs out as undefined. However, for this 
code, it is grabbing information from an input field on client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code data hasn't returned a value yet. You need to store the result on a reactive variable or a session variable.